# Coq - Assign expression to variable

Tags: coq

First and foremost, I'm not yet very familiar with Coq lingo, so I will use terms like e.g. 'expression' and 'variable' loosely, but they are probably not the correct Coq terms.

I'm trying to prove the following subgoal of a Theorem.

```
1 goal
b : bag
v, b' : nat
b'' : natlist
B : b = b' :: b''
IHb'' : b = b'' -> count v (add v b'') = count v b'' + 1
______________________________________(1/1)
S match v =? b' with
  | true => S (count v b'')
  | false => count v b''
  end = match v =? b' with
        | true => S (count v b'')
        | false => count v b''
        end + 1
```

You can ignore `S` and `+ 1`, I'm basically looking for a way to assign

```
match v =? b' with
  | true => S (count v b'')
  | false => count v b''
  end
```

to a variable of type `nat` because it occurs on both sides of the equation.
How can I do this? Or do I need to go through destroying `v` and `b'` and proving all cases separately?

Comment: It's indeed less confusing to replace that large expression by a variable, but note that you don't *need*  to do it. A proof of `S x = x + 1` should work verbatim on your goal.

Comment: Thanks that was the tip I needed, I just proved this and everything worked out. Working my way through softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/ , I'm not yet allowed to use the Coq constructs from the answers to my question.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two possibilities. There may well be better ones.

You can use [`set`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html?highlight=set#coq:tacn.set) to give a name to a term. All the occurrences of that term are replaced by the variable.

```
set (x := match v =? b' with
          | true => S (count v b'')
          | false => count v b''
          end).
```

Sometimes you need to hide the definition of the variable, and only remember it as an equality that you invoke on demand. For that, use [`remember`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.remember).

You can match the goal against a pattern using the [`context`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#match-term-context) form of [`match goal`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#ltac-match-goal) and give a name to whatever's inside that pattern.

```
match goal with |- context [S ?_x = ?_x + 1] => set (x := _x) end.
```

If this is your real goal and not a simplified example, it's a simple arithmetic statement and you can just call [`lia`](https://coq.github.io/doc/v8.13/refman/addendum/micromega.html#coq:tacn.lia) and let Coq figure it out.

```
Require Import Lia.

…
lia.
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides Gilles's suggestions you can use the [ssreflect](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ssreflect-proof-language.html) [`set`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ssreflect-proof-language.html#coq:tacn.set-(ssreflect)) to achieve this, in at least two ways illustrated here:

```
Require Import Arith ssreflect.

Variables v b' b'' : nat.
Variable count : nat -> nat -> nat.

Goal
 S match v =? b' with
   | true => S (count v b'')
   | false => count v b''
   end
 = match v =? b' with
   | true => S (count v b'')
   | false => count v b''
   end + 1.
Proof.
  set t := (X in S X = X + _).
  Undo.
  set t := match _ with true => _ | false => _ end.
Abort.
```

The latter one also works with the [regular `set`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.set) but it needs brackets:

```
  set (t := match _ with true => _ | false => _ end).
```